# Symfony 5 PreUpdate change value for only one true

Tags: php, symfony, events, lifecycle

Hello and thank you for your concern.
i'am student and it's my first time creating an eventSubriber.
I would like to change all my attribute "**display**" (Boolean) in my Entity "**Menu**" when i try to update one of my entity "Menu" for have only one Attribute "display" true in all my entities.
I use EasyAdmin 3 in my project Symfony if you need to know.
My probleme start with $this->entityManager->flush(); in UniqueBoolTureEvent.php i think.

thank you in advance.

Service.yaml

```
App\EventListener\UniqueBoolTrueEvent:
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: preUpdate, Lazy: true }
```

UniqueBoolTrueEvent.php

```
  <?php
    
    namespace App\EventListener;
    
    
    use App\Entity\Menu;
    use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
    // Entity to listen
    use Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectManager;
    use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs;
    
    
    class UniqueBoolTrueEvent implements EventSubscriber {
    
        private $entityManager;
    
        /**
         * @param EntityManagerInterface $entityManager
         */
        public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
        {
            $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        }
    
        public function getSubscribedEvents() {
            return array('preUpdate');//Event to listen
        }
    
        public function preUpdate(  PreUpdateEventArgs $eventArgs ) {
    
    
                    
            if ($eventArgs->getEntity() instanceof Menu) {
                if ($eventArgs->hasChangedField('display') && $eventArgs->getNewValue('display') == 'true') {
                   //get the id of entity change for true
                    $entityId = $eventArgs->getEntity()->getId();

    // search the entity already on true exept entity change now
                    $displayTrue =  $this->entityManager->getRepository(Menu::class)->findByDisplay($entityId);
    
//Change the value for entity already on true exept entity change now
                    foreach ($displayTrue as $display) {
                         $display->setDisplay(false);
                         $this->entityManager->persist($display);
                    }
                   
                    
                    $this->entityManager->flush();
                }
            }
    
            
        }
    
    }
```

MenuRepository.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\Menu;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;

/**
 * @method Menu|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method Menu|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method Menu[]    findAll()
 * @method Menu[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */
class MenuRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    /**
     * @param ManagerRegistry $registry
     */
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Menu::class);
    }


      /**
      * @return Menu[] Returns an array of Menu objects
      */
    public function findByDisplay($entityId)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('m')
            ->andWhere('m.display = true')
            ->andWhere('m.id != :entityId')
            ->setParameter('entityId', $entityId)
            ->orderBy('m.id', 'ASC')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
        ;
    }
}
```

after that i have only one error in my ajax request and cannot see where is the probleme.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My Solution No 2 Solutions lol

First solution with EventSubscriberInterface and BeforeEntityUpdatedEvent. With this solution you don't need to add config in service.yaml

```
class UniqueBoolTrueEvent implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $entityManager;
 
        /**
         * @param EntityManagerInterface $entityManager
         */
        public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
        {
            $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        }
 
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            BeforeEntityUpdatedEvent::class => ['setDisplayTrue'],
        ];
    }
 
    public function setDisplayTrue(BeforeEntityUpdatedEvent $event)
    {
        $entity = $event->getEntityInstance();
        $entityId = $entity->getId();
 
         
 
         
        if ($entity instanceof Menu) {
            $displayTrue =  $this->entityManager->getRepository(Menu::class)->findByDisplay($entityId);
 
            foreach ($displayTrue as $display) {
                 
                $display->setDisplay(false);
                $this->entityManager->persist($display);
            }
                                    
                                     
            $this->entityManager->flush();
        }
 
    }
}
```

And my second solution with onFlush()

service.yaml

```
App\EventListener\UniqueBoolTrueEvent:
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: onFlush}
```

UniqueBoolTrueEvent.php

class UniqueBoolTrueEvent
{

```
private $entityManager;

/**
 * @param EntityManagerInterface $entityManager
 */
public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
{
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
}


public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $eventArgs)
{
    $em = $eventArgs->getEntityManager();
    $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

    $entities = $uow->getScheduledEntityUpdates();

    foreach ($entities as $entity) {
         
            //continue only if the object to be updated is a Ticket
        if ($entity instanceof Menu) {
            $entityId = $entity->getId();
            $entityDisplay = $entity->getDisplay();
             
            // //get all the changed properties of the Menu object
            // $changes_set = $uow->getEntityChangeSet($entity);

            //Check if the changed value of "display" is True
            if ($entityDisplay == true) {
                //find the entity with "display" value true exept the entity update
                $displayTrue =  $this->entityManager->getRepository(Menu::class)->findByDisplay($entityId);

                    // Change the value of "display" to false for each entity on true exept the entity update
                foreach ($displayTrue as $display) {
                    $display->setDisplay(false);
                     
                    $em->persist($display);
                    // for flush
                    $classMetadata = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity));
                    // dd($classMetadata);
                    $uow->computeChangeSet($classMetadata, $display);
                }
            }

            
        }
    }
}
```

}